# Android Layout: options between center and top

Tags: android, layout

I want layout a textview in its parent, sometimes as vertical center, and sometimes only set topMargin(10), I use code as following :

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textview.getLayoutParams;

    params.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
    params.topMargin = 0;
    if(condition){
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    }else{
        params.topMargin = 10;
    }

    textview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and I use linearLayout , but code does not work. The following is piece of my xml:

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
... other wigdet
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you creating textview programmatically or through xml?

Comment: Did you try LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textview.getLayoutParams(); and then setting the gravity?

Comment: You are great, it work. But how can I clear gravity/topMargin while switch between two layouts? I try but make me confuse.

Comment: In if-condition, you can set topmargin as 0 and set gravity. In else-condition, you can replace gravity with your initial gravity which you specified in xml.

Comment: I set topMargin as 0 and gravity as NO_GRAVITY, but is still not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106362/discussion-between-srijith-n-and-dxxxbooo).